# Can a PPT adversary get secret $a$ from public messages $m_i=x_i-a \mod p-1$ for i=1,2, ...,n?

Tags: keys, randomness

Consider I have a secret $a \in Z_P^*$ and n public messages where $m_i=x_i -a \mod p-1$ and $x_i  \in Z_p$ for i=1,2, ..., n. Given that $a$ and $x_i$ for $i=1,2, ..., n$ are secrets, can a PPT adversary get the value of $a$ or $x_i$?

I have an impression that it is difficult because this problem would be similar to solving n linear equations with n+1 unknowns, any contribution would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> can a PPT adversary get the value of $a$ or $x_i$?

As written, no, the adversary has no information on any specific value of $a$ or $x_i$ (even if we assume a computationally unbounded adversary, which is a far weaker assumption than a PPT adversary).

This can be seen by the observation that if we set any of the unknowns to any specific value (two examples, if $a=42$ or if $x_3 = 31$), then there is a unique solution for all the other unknown variables.  Because any variable setting is compatible with everything the attacker knows, he has no way to distinguish which one is correct.

That said, this is also rather brittle; if the attacker learns any one of the unknowns, then (by the above observation), he also learns all the other unknowns.  More subtly, if he has probabilistic information on the unknown variable settings, that may be enough (depending on the probability distribution) to recover a 'most likely' setting.

Comment: Also, $a$ needs to be from the full range of possible $a$ values, else $m_i$ are leaking the high parts of $x_i$.  Just mentioning this for answer's sake.

Comment: For reasons unclear, $a$ is chosen from $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ in the question. This invalidates the analysis in this answer. For each $x_i$ we can trivially rule out one value, namely $m_i$.

Comment: @Maeher: I believe that the argument still hold; if the attacker had knowledge of the probability distribution of $a$ before he learns the $x_i$ values, that knowledge remains the same afterwards (that is, he doesn't learn anything he didn't already know).  By specifying $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$, that means that the value $a=0$ has probability 0; the doesn't change the argument.  Now, if the values of $x_i$ were also specified to be in $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$, you would have a point - the question doesn't say that

Comment: While the *title* of the question is only concerned about hiding $a$, the body of the question also mentions hiding $x_i$.